# sublime text exit multiple selection state with keyboard

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have no idea when I try to exit multiple selection state in sublme text with keyboard.

I don't want to use the mouse.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple-choice? Can you give an example?

Comment: Hi,man! I can't upload a picture.I mean this "shift + mouse left"——select multiple rows.What should I do when I try to exit ?

Comment: You can try the arrow keys to deselect when you've selected multiple rows. Do you mean multiple selection? https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Comment: Thank you,man!I found a way to solve the problem.I used the Esc，but it will be the command mode.I add ignored_packages:["Vintage"] in Settings-User,It is great now. Anyway,thanks for your help and I feel sorry for my poor English. XD   What should I do to close the question?

Comment: First of all, would you please update your post to make it clearer? Then, you should post your answer and accept it in case someone else meets the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to fix it.

- Firstly, try to read the doc:https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html
- secondly, Maybe the editor become **command mode** when you useing  *Esc* try to exit the multiple selection state. Opening Setting-User and adding `"ignored_packages":["Vintage"]`.It will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Even as of Sublime Text 3.2.1 exiting multi-line mode is difficult by default. Instead of switching to vintage mode, you may also bind a new key to exit multi-line mode, which I find a better solution as escape has other functions already that can conflict.

The relevant (default) keybindings are:

```
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+l"], "command": "split_selection_into_lines" },
    { "keys": ["escape"], "command": "single_selection", "context":
        [
            { "key": "num_selections", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": 1 }
        ]
    }
```

In my case I added

```
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+;"], "command": "single_selection", "context":
        [
            { "key": "num_selections", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": 1 }
        ]
    }
```

to my user bindings, but you may choose any key combination you prefer.